# Convert $(document).ready() function into window.onload function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.post("../user/getdashboard/", function(data) {
        $("#users_available").html(data);
    });
  }, 3000);
}
```

I have to convert it into `window.onload` function.

How to do it?

Comment: `$(window).on('load', function() { ...`

Comment: The question is, why do you want to convert it? A `ready state` and `window load` are two different things. So what is your reason?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean. Why would you need to convert it?

Comment: Instead of `$( document ).ready(function()` , I have to use `window.onload`

Comment: Why do you **have to**? There must be reason?!

Comment: Yes, you said that already in the question and in the title. We're asking **why** you have to do that.

Comment: @BeginnerDev let's try to be more direct, is this homework which requires you to do it in a specific way?

Comment: yes, I have to do it in the way @Script47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it vanilla js, use `onload` callback of the `window` object:

```
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.post("../user/getdashboard/", function(data) {
        $("#users_available" ).html(data);
    });
  }, 3000);
}
```

But you could even use `load` event with `jQuery`, what is basically the same:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.post("../user/getdashboard/", function(data) {
        $("#users_available").html(data);
    });
  }, 3000);
});
```

But keep in mind, that a jQuery `ready state` is not the same as `window.onload`. These are two different things. So this might have unexpected impacts to your project/page.

Answer (score -1):

You can handle the `readystatechange` event,

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

`window.onload` waits for everything, including images, which probably is overkill.